# How do you timestamp code-signed Dotnet assemblies?

Tags: .net, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

When you are using a code-signing certificate to sign your assemblies, how do you ensure that the code has a timestamp?

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3428386/2608) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4417410/2608) for more details about why you need a timestamp on a signed assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below build event to ensure that your assemblies are both signed and timestamped:

```
if $(ConfigurationName)==Release "$(FrameworkSDKDir)bin\signtool.exe" sign /a /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll "$(TargetPath)"
```

See the [SignTool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz.aspx) article at MSDN and have a look at the `/t` (timestamp) switch.