# Code-signature expiration on already signed files

Tags: windows, code-signing, code-signing-certificate, authenticode, signtool

I was using Microsoft's [SignTool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz.aspx) to sign my executables with my code signing certificate using the following command line call:

```
signtool.exe sign /q /f "cert.pfx" /p "pfxpassword" /d "File Description" /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll "file2sign.exe"
```

My code signing certificate will expire in November of this year. From what I understand, if I renew it, I will be issued a new code-signing certificate. So in that case my question is, what will happen to the software that was already signed with my current certificate -- do I need to resign it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should we set a timestamp when we do a codesigning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417410/why-should-we-set-a-timestamp-when-we-do-a-codesigning), that will answer the user's question.