# http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll not available

Tags: installation, signtool

When the following URL is not available, what other timestamp URL can I use in my setup authoring tool? The specific error I get is: `SignTool Error: The specified timestamp server either could not be reached or returned an invalid response.`

http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll

Comment: One note though. If you get 404 doing a GET request (i.e. fetching that page using a browser), that doesn't mean that the service is unavailable. The TSP (time-stamp protocol) over HTTP is usually handled using a POST request, with a specific Content-Type HTTP header (application/timestamp-query). More info on these 2 links: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3161.txt and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28085619/timestamping-using-tsa-url-and-java-apis

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Honestly, I would just try again. But you can use any of the following:

- `http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll`,
- `http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode`, or
- `http://www.startssl.com/timestamp`.
- `http://timestamp.sectigo.com`

Comment: I did, but today it really does not respond.

Comment: @Alain Endpoint http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll worked for me. The Verisign wasn't available yesterday :-(

Answer (score 24):

Try these servers

```
http://tsa.starfieldtech.com
http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll
http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode
http://www.startssl.com/timestamp
http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll
http://timestamp.sectigo.com
```

With a retry script such as the one included here:
[Alternative timestamping services for Authenticode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872105/alternative-timestamping-services-for-authenticode/12160486#12160486)

Comment: Today it looks like timestamp.verisign.com is gone.  My DNS providers cannot resolve it.  Thanks for these alternatives!

Comment: If someone uses the FinalBuilder tool, this is a good article explaining how to try different servers: https://www.finalbuilder.com/resources/blogs/code-signing-changes-for-2016 with a great sample code ready-to-use: https://github.com/VSoftTechnologies/FinalBuilder.Examples/blob/master/FB8/CodeSigning/CodeSigningExample.fbp8

Answer (score 19):

http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll has limped along for the last few years and had been working in a sort of depreciated state, but the new owners of the certificate issuing business, DigiCert, have issued a migration alert.

They have officially put the old services to EOL as of the back end of 2019.

(article no no longer exists 18/11/2020)
https://knowledge.digicert.com/alerts/migration-of-legacy-verisign-and-symantec-time-stamping-services.html

[image: DigiCert TSA]

New services can be found at

> http://timestamp.digicert.com?alg=sha1
>
> http://timestamp.digicert.com?alg=sha256

[Troubleshooting time stamping](https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO912.html)

Comment: I am getting the same, not sure what is going raised a ticket with them, latest guidence shows the url is correct. https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO912.html

Comment: suddenly this works: http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll

Answer (score 3):

For jarsigner users:

As of 4/24/2017, Verisign knowledge base article AR185 recommends the jarsigner arguments "-tsa http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp". This works for certificates issued by Symantec, and presumably all of Symantec's subsidiaries, at least. http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll does not work.

Answer (score 2):

This list of time servers seems to be getting regular updates: https://gist.github.com/Manouchehri/fd754e402d98430243455713efada710

Answer (score 1):

You can use "http://timestamp.digicert.com" without quotes.
for more info: https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO912.html

Answer (score 0):

Try these servers

```
http://timestamp.digicert.com
http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode
```

other links is dead

`SignTool Error: The specified timestamp server either could not be reached or returned an invalid response.`