# Time stamp validation, missing certificate

Tags: openssl, timestamp, certificate

**What I need:**
I need a verifiable time stamp on a file called `notes`, on my Ubuntu computer using `openssl`.

**What my problem is:**
I can get a signed timestamp from http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll but I can't verify it.  When I run

```
openssl ts -verify -data notes -in test.tsr
```

I get the two-line output (extra line breaks inserted for readability)

```
Verification: FAILED

3073500860:error:2F06D064:time stamp routines:
TS_VERIFY_CERT:certificate verify error:ts_rsp_verify.c:246:
Verify error:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

*I think what this means* is that I need a certificate named "GlobalSign TSA for Standard - G2" (see "output of script" section below), but I have no idea where to find it.  I `grep`'d my `/usr`, `/etc`, and `/home` directories for that string, so I'm pretty confident I actually don't have it.  I can't find it on the google. **Does anybody know where to get this certificate, or maybe I'm doing something else wrong?**  And also, why is this so difficult?  I see lots of people talking about using this server on various stack exchanges, but I seem to be the only one with this problem.

---

**More info**

I am using the default `openssl` config file at `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`.

I use the following short script to generate a time stamp query `test.tsq`, then send it to the time stamp server, receive a time stamp reply `test.tsr`, then try to validate it.

```
#!/bin/bash
#make time stamp query
openssl ts -query -data notes -sha256 -cert -out test.tsq

#write query to stdout in text format
openssl ts -query -in test.tsq -text

echo ""

#use tsget to get the request, since I don't know how to do it with curl
tsget -h http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll test.tsq

#write the reply to stdout in text form
openssl ts -reply -in test.tsr -text

echo ""

#verify the timestamp
openssl ts -verify -data notes -in test.tsr
```

The `perl` script `tsget` came with the `openssl` package I think, and I found it at `/usr/lib/ssl/misc/tsget`, but I'll include it here for troubleshooting:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# Written by Zoltan Glozik <zglozik@stones.com>.
# Copyright (c) 2002 The OpenTSA Project.  All rights reserved.
$::version = '$Id: tsget,v 1.3 2009/09/07 17:57:18 steve Exp $';

use strict;
use IO::Handle;
use Getopt::Std;
use File::Basename;
use WWW::Curl::Easy;

use vars qw(%options);

# Callback for reading the body.
sub read_body {
    my ($maxlength, $state) = @_;
    my $return_data = "";
    my $data_len = length ${$state->{data}};
    if ($state->{bytes} < $data_len) {
    $data_len = $data_len - $state->{bytes};
    $data_len = $maxlength if $data_len > $maxlength;
    $return_data = substr ${$state->{data}}, $state->{bytes}, $data_len;
    $state->{bytes} += $data_len;
    }
    return $return_data;
}

# Callback for writing the body into a variable.
sub write_body {
    my ($data, $pointer) = @_;
    ${$pointer} .= $data;
    return length($data);
}

# Initialise a new Curl object.
sub create_curl {
    my $url = shift;

    # Create Curl object.
    my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy::new();

    # Error-handling related options.
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1) if $options{d};
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "OpenTSA tsget.pl/" . (split / /, $::version)[2]);

    # Options for POST method.
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        ["Content-Type: application/timestamp-query",
        "Accept: application/timestamp-reply,application/timestamp-response"]);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, \&read_body);
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, sub { return length($_[0]); });

    # Options for getting the result.
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, \&write_body);

    # SSL related options.
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE, "PEM");
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);   # Verify server's certificate.
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);   # Check server's CN.
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $options{k}) if defined($options{k});
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, $options{p}) if defined($options{p});
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $options{c}) if defined($options{c});
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_CAINFO, $options{C}) if defined($options{C});
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_CAPATH, $options{P}) if defined($options{P});
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_RANDOM_FILE, $options{r}) if defined($options{r});
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_EGDSOCKET, $options{g}) if defined($options{g});

    # Setting destination.
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    return $curl;
}

# Send a request and returns the body back.
sub get_timestamp {
    my $curl = shift;
    my $body = shift;
    my $ts_body;
    local $::error_buf;

    # Error-handling related options.
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, "::error_buf");

    # Options for POST method.
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_INFILE, {data => $body, bytes => 0});
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, length(${$body}));

    # Options for getting the result.
    $curl->setopt(CURLOPT_FILE, \$ts_body);

    # Send the request...
    my $error_code = $curl->perform();
    my $error_string;
    if ($error_code != 0) {
        my $http_code = $curl->getinfo(CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $error_string = "could not get timestamp";
    $error_string .= ", http code: $http_code" unless $http_code == 0;
    $error_string .= ", curl code: $error_code";
    $error_string .= " ($::error_buf)" if defined($::error_buf);
    } else {
        my $ct = $curl->getinfo(CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
    if (lc($ct) ne "application/timestamp-reply"
        && lc($ct) ne "application/timestamp-response") {
        $error_string = "unexpected content type returned: $ct";
        }
    }
    return ($ts_body, $error_string);

}

# Print usage information and exists.
sub usage {

    print STDERR "usage: $0 -h <server_url> [-e <extension>] [-o <output>] ";
    print STDERR "[-v] [-d] [-k <private_key.pem>] [-p <key_password>] ";
    print STDERR "[-c <client_cert.pem>] [-C <CA_certs.pem>] [-P <CA_path>] ";
    print STDERR "[-r <file:file...>] [-g <EGD_socket>] [<request>]...\n";
    exit 1;
}

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Main program
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Getting command-line options (default comes from TSGET environment variable).
my $getopt_arg =  "h:e:o:vdk:p:c:C:P:r:g:";
if (exists $ENV{TSGET}) {
    my @old_argv = @ARGV;
    @ARGV = split /\s+/, $ENV{TSGET};
    getopts($getopt_arg, \%options) or usage;
    @ARGV = @old_argv;
}
getopts($getopt_arg, \%options) or usage;

# Checking argument consistency.
if (!exists($options{h}) || (@ARGV == 0 && !exists($options{o}))
    || (@ARGV > 1 && exists($options{o}))) {
    print STDERR "Inconsistent command line options.\n";
    usage;
}
# Setting defaults.
@ARGV = ("-") unless @ARGV != 0;
$options{e} = ".tsr" unless defined($options{e});

# Processing requests.
my $curl = create_curl $options{h};
undef $/;   # For reading whole files.
REQUEST: foreach (@ARGV) {
    my $input = $_;
    my ($base, $path) = fileparse($input, '\.[^.]*');
    my $output_base = $base . $options{e};
    my $output = defined($options{o}) ? $options{o} : $path . $output_base;

    STDERR->printflush("$input: ") if $options{v};
    # Read request.
    my $body;
    if ($input eq "-") {
    # Read the request from STDIN;
    $body = <STDIN>;
    } else {
    # Read the request from file.
        open INPUT, "<" . $input
        or warn("$input: could not open input file: $!\n"), next REQUEST;
        $body = <INPUT>;
        close INPUT
        or warn("$input: could not close input file: $!\n"), next REQUEST;
    }

    # Send request.
    STDERR->printflush("sending request") if $options{v};

    my ($ts_body, $error) = get_timestamp $curl, \$body;
    if (defined($error)) {
    die "$input: fatal error: $error\n";
    }
    STDERR->printflush(", reply received") if $options{v};

    # Write response.
    if ($output eq "-") {
    # Write to STDOUT.
        print $ts_body;
    } else {
    # Write to file.
        open OUTPUT, ">", $output
        or warn("$output: could not open output file: $!\n"), next REQUEST;
        print OUTPUT $ts_body;
        close OUTPUT
        or warn("$output: could not close output file: $!\n"), next REQUEST;
    }
    STDERR->printflush(", $output written.\n") if $options{v};
}
$curl->cleanup();
WWW::Curl::Easy::global_cleanup();
```

**Output of Script**

```
Version: 1
Hash Algorithm: sha256
Message data:
    0000 - a8 31 60 9c a3 fe 14 74-05 f1 be 78 89 5c a6 a5   .1`....t...x.\..
    0010 - d3 b7 4a 7d 18 b9 d0 f9-39 fc a8 d6 e2 be 2e 27   ..J}....9......'
Policy OID: unspecified
Nonce: 0x533AC264C90C4EEE
Certificate required: yes
Extensions:

Undefined subroutine &WWW::Curl::Easy::global_cleanup called at /usr/local/bin/tsget line 196.
Status info:
Status: Granted.
Status description: unspecified
Failure info: unspecified

TST info:
Version: 1
Policy OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4146.2.2
Hash Algorithm: sha256
Message data:
    0000 - a8 31 60 9c a3 fe 14 74-05 f1 be 78 89 5c a6 a5   .1`....t...x.\..
    0010 - d3 b7 4a 7d 18 b9 d0 f9-39 fc a8 d6 e2 be 2e 27   ..J}....9......'
Serial number: 0x3A668E2441A3707CB495191DC3EF2D717C49DD30
Time stamp: Sep 25 16:55:34 2015 GMT
Accuracy: unspecified
Ordering: no
Nonce: 0x533AC264C90C4EEE
TSA: DirName:/C=SG/O=GMO GlobalSign Pte Ltd/CN=GlobalSign TSA for Standard - G2
Extensions:

Verification: FAILED
3073967804:error:2F06D064:time stamp routines:TS_VERIFY_CERT:certificate verify error:ts_rsp_verify.c:246:Verify error:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did find the answer: http://tsa.safecreative.org/

After much googling, I started to get the impression that although posts like this one [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872105/alternative-timestamping-services-for-authenticode) and [this one](http://unmitigatedrisk.com/?p=395) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714798/http-timestamp-verisign-com-scripts-timstamp-dll-not-available) and especially [this one](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9491/on-line-cryptographically-signed-date-time) made it seem like GlobalSign and Verisign and friends each run a free timestamping server, I am now under the impression that they're not really free.  I think it's a free "add on" to some other products they sell, perhaps.  It is possible for anybody to get a timestamp from their servers, but I can't validate that timestamp without their certificate, which does not seem to be freely available.  If anybody knows otherwise, they are free to correct me.

On the other hand, http://tsa.safecreative.org/ is an actually free website (or, up to 5 stamps per day per IP address free), where anybody can download their certificate to verify the timestamp.  That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: *"... I am now under the impression that they're not really free. I think it's a free "add on" to some other products they sell..."* - yeah, you gotta love the games companies play....

Comment: Also see [Wishlist: provide Timestamp services](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/wishlist-provide-timestamp-services/1350) on the [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) community bulletin board.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the "GlobalSign Root CA" ([found here](https://github.com/envylabs/openssl-extensions/blob/master/spec/fixtures/certificates/globalsign-root-ca.pem) and [here](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1426602-globalsign-root-certificates) on the official site as "R1 GlobalSign Root Certificate")  you need to validate your TSR :

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDdTCCAl2gAwIBAgILBAAAAAABFUtaw5QwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwVzELMAkG
A1UEBhMCQkUxGTAXBgNVBAoTEEdsb2JhbFNpZ24gbnYtc2ExEDAOBgNVBAsTB1Jv
b3QgQ0ExGzAZBgNVBAMTEkdsb2JhbFNpZ24gUm9vdCBDQTAeFw05ODA5MDExMjAw
MDBaFw0yODAxMjgxMjAwMDBaMFcxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkJFMRkwFwYDVQQKExBHbG9i
YWxTaWduIG52LXNhMRAwDgYDVQQLEwdSb290IENBMRswGQYDVQQDExJHbG9iYWxT
aWduIFJvb3QgQ0EwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQDaDuaZ
jc6j40+Kfvvxi4Mla+pIH/EqsLmVEQS98GPR4mdmzxzdzxtIK+6NiY6arymAZavp
xy0Sy6scTHAHoT0KMM0VjU/43dSMUBUc71DuxC73/OlS8pF94G3VNTCOXkNz8kHp
1Wrjsok6Vjk4bwY8iGlbKk3Fp1S4bInMm/k8yuX9ifUSPJJ4ltbcdG6TRGHRjcdG
snUOhugZitVtbNV4FpWi6cgKOOvyJBNPc1STE4U6G7weNLWLBYy5d4ux2x8gkasJ
U26Qzns3dLlwR5EiUWMWea6xrkEmCMgZK9FGqkjWZCrXgzT/LCrBbBlDSgeF59N8
9iFo7+ryUp9/k5DPAgMBAAGjQjBAMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIBBjAPBgNVHRMBAf8E
BTADAQH/MB0GA1UdDgQWBBRge2YaRQ2XyolQL30EzTSo//z9SzANBgkqhkiG9w0B
AQUFAAOCAQEA1nPnfE920I2/7LqivjTFKDK1fPxsnCwrvQmeU79rXqoRSLblCKOz
yj1hTdNGCbM+w6DjY1Ub8rrvrTnhQ7k4o+YviiY776BQVvnGCv04zcQLcFGUl5gE
38NflNUVyRRBnMRddWQVDf9VMOyGj/8N7yy5Y0b2qvzfvGn9LhJIZJrglfCm7ymP
AbEVtQwdpf5pLGkkeB6zpxxxYu7KyJesF12KwvhHhm4qxFYxldBniYUr+WymXUad
DKqC5JlR3XC321Y9YeRq4VzW9v493kHMB65jUr9TU/Qr6cf9tveCX4XSQRjbgbME
HMUfpIBvFSDJ3gyICh3WZlXi/EjJKSZp4A==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Save it to `root.pem`

Moreover you need to extract too all the chain of the intermediate certificates used to sign the timestamp response.

First of all, make a request with the `-cert` option (to include certificate chain) :

```
#make time stamp query
openssl ts -query -data notes -sha256 -cert -out test.tsq
```

To get the TSR, Ask the TSA with :

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/timestamp-query' --data-binary '@test.tsq' http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll > test.tsr
```

Then extract certificates with :

```
openssl ts -reply -in test.tsr -token_out | openssl pkcs7 -inform der -print_certs | sed -n '/-----BEGIN/,/-----END/p' > chain.pem
```

Then you can verify your timestamp response with :

```
#verify the timestamp
openssl ts -verify -data notes -in test.tsr -CAfile root.pem -untrusted chain.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a timestamp in Windows, then export the certificate chain from the timestamped executable and you have the chain.