# Why is Install4j executable signing not working any more?

Tags: install4j

I'm trying to build an Install4j project that was working fine a few weeks ago, but now it's complaining about a timestamp service not being available while the executable is being signed. Is there another timestamp service we should be using or is this one only temporarily offline?

I'm using Install4j 7.0.12.

```
Preparing configuration

Creating media file 'Windows':
  Collecting files:
  Compiling launchers:
    Compiling launcher 'test':
      Signing executable

Build failed.

Cause: java.io.IOException
       http://timestamp.globalsign.com
       You can set a different timestamp signing service by setting the VM parameter -Dinstall4j.timestampUrl=http://... in bin/install4j.vmoptions
       or by setting the compiler variable sys.ext.timestampUrl in your project.
Cause: java.io.FileNotFoundException
       http://timestamp.globalsign.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an entry to *General Settings > Compiler Variables* with the following details seems to do the trick:

```
sys.ext.timestampUrl = http://timestamp.sectigo.com
```

This is probably related to [http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll not available](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9714798/475511).

Comment: Actually, the URL that does not work anymore is `http://timestamp.globalsign.com`. Another timestamp server that works is `http://timestamp.digicert.com`, thsi is used by recent versions of install4j. Also, you can add the line `-Dinstall4j.timestampUrl=http://timestamp.digicert.com` to `bin/install4j.vmoptions`. Then it will work for all projects again.