# Is the Verisign Timestamp server down?

Tags: inno-setup, code-signing, verisign

I was trying to build my setup scripts with Inno Setup these past two days (1 & 2 Jan 2021) and the digital signing was failing. So I contacted Verisign via email and await their response.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I received an official response from Verisign this afternoon (on 2 Jan 2021):

> Thank you for contacting Verisign Support.
>
> This server was deprecated after our authentication services were sold
> to Symantec, which is now Digicert.  You can find a list of free
> timestamp servers online or theirs is now at
> http://timestamp.digicert.com.
>
> If you have additional questions, please do not hesitate to contact
> us.

So the `http://timestamp.verisign.com` timestamp server is no more.

At the moment I know of the following alternatives (in addition to Digicert above) which work well:

- `http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode`
- `http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll`
- `http://tsa.starfieldtech.com`

Comment: I wasn't able to find any public posts about this. Did they point you to any deprecation announcements? It seems like this was completely announced.

Comment: @AlannaRose No, I emailed their support and I copy / pasted their response to me.

Comment: Note about http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode : I stopped using that one in June 2020 because it started generating broken timestamps, I believe due to an expired root certificate.

Comment: Another note about http://tsa.starfieldtech.com: this one does not seem reliable, I think it bans IP that do "too much" signing.

Comment: Tried pinging the timestamp.digicert.com today and got Request timed out.
timestamp.globalsign.com appears to be alive.

Comment: Another one you can use is `http://timestamp.sectigo.com` (see https://sectigo.com/resource-library/time-stamping-server for details)

Comment: Regarding ping: *The timestamping server will not respond to any other network probes (such as a ping or a tracert.)*. This is from https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO912.html

Comment: Even I am getting this below, is this down ?                                                                                            
 Failed to convert timestamp reply from http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode; HTTP status 404

Comment: @JDGuide when I clicked that link it redirected to: https://sectigo.com/resource-library/time-stamping-server. Did you see the comment  dated Jan 7, 2021 by WimCoenen ?

Answer (score 32):

When using Microsoft's [**SignTool.exe**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe)

Change the timestamping server (`-t`):

- **Before**: `signcode -t "http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll"` *(defunct)*
- **After**:    `signcode -t "http://timestamp.digicert.com"`

Comment: If someone was already signing their executables they would surely know how to change the server used for the timestamp?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Exactly. And in order to help along the process, and since stackoverflow is also a wiki, i'm providing the information to others to help them along. No reason they have to suffer through remembering all these details that they laid down in a `.cmd` file 17 years ago and haven't thought about since.

Comment: Fair enough. Then you might want to flesh your answer out with a direct link to teh SignTool documentation at Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signtool Up to you!

Comment: @IanBoyd This was a life saver. The 'someone' left the company and left no instructions. The server that had the data crashed and there were no backups. Two groups thought the other group was responsible for backups. So I was left with black hole.