# Comodo - signing code - issue with timestamp

Tags: code-signing, autoit

I use:

```
; Create COM objects
; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signedcode
Local $oSignedCode = ObjCreate("CAPICOM.SignedCode.1")


; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signedcode-signer
; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signer
Local $oSigner = ObjCreate("CAPICOM.Signer.1")

; Load certificate - Who Is Signing
$oSigner.Load($s_FileFullPath_Certificat, $s_Password)
```

and I have no problem with signing:

```
$oSignedCode.Sign($oSigner)
```

my problem starts in 2021 and is realted to timestamping.

As so far I was using:

```
; TimeStampIt
$oSignedCode.Timestamp("https://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll")
```

But when 2021 starts I constantly get this kind of error:

> Error.description is:     An unknown error has occured. Please contact your vendor for assistance.

I was trying to find other TimeStamp server:

```
$oSignedCode.Timestamp("http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp")
$oSignedCode.Timestamp("http://timestamp.comodoca.com")
$oSignedCode.Timestamp("http://timestamp.comodoca.com?td=SHA-384")
$oSignedCode.Timestamp("http://timestamp.sectigo.com/qualified")
```

but no one of there works.

**QUESTION:** How to fix the problem with timestamping ?

Regards,
Michał

EDIT: btw... I use COMODO certificate for signing.

Comment: Maybe this will work? http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this URL:
`http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll`
instead.

In your code:
`$oSignedCode.Timestamp("http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll")`

Comment: from this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65541786/is-the-verisign-timestamp-server-down