# Remove URL from Signtool

Tags: asp.net, certificate, signtool

BUMP: any thoughts or suggestions?

Building my web application has been throwing the following errors:

- The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64\signtool.exe" sign /a /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll "application.exe"" exited with code 1
- An error occurred while attempting to sign: application.exe
- The specified timestamp server either could not be reach or

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65541786/is-the-verisign-timestamp-server-down), I added different servers with something like
`signtool sign /v /td sha256 /tr "http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161" /fd sha1 application.exe`

but my build still references the Verisign URL even after running this `signtool catdb /r http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll` and `signtool remove http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll`

Any ideas? Do I need to create a new certificate? Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found what the problem was. There was a Build Event setting this reference to Verisign. Once I found it and updated, the build was successful.

The location of this is r-click on the project < select Properties < select the Compile tab < click button for Build Events...

Hope this helps any others.